# How do I stick Controls inside of ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

Is it generally possible to avoid moving some controls while Scrolling?

In particular is it possible to stick the first row (with lightblue background) in the following code example:

```
<Grid>
  <ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        <RowDefinition />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Canvas Background="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" />
      <Grid  Grid.Row="1" >
        <Canvas Background="Beige" Width="100" Height="800" />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this?

```
<Grid> 
  <ScrollViewer> 
<Grid Height="800" Width="480" > 
  <Canvas Background="Beige" Width="100" Height="800" /> 
</Grid> 
  </ScrollViewer>
  <Canvas Background="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" /> 
</Grid>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
    <Setter.Value>
      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
      </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                CornerRadius="2">
          <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
              <RowDefinition/>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter"
                                    Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
                                    ContentTemplate=
                                      "{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="#FFE9EEF4" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       IsTabStop="False"
                       Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                       Margin="0,-1,-1,-1"
                       Minimum="0"
                       Orientation="Vertical"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Visibility="{TemplateBinding
                         ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                       Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                       ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                       Width="18"
                       Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
            <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Height="18"
                       IsTabStop="False"
                       Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                       Margin="-1,0,-1,-18"
                       Minimum="0"
                       Orientation="Horizontal"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       Visibility="{TemplateBinding
                         ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                       Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                       ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FF89B1E2"/>
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

So if you want Vertical ScrollBar to go all the way to the top you can create a style for the ScrollViewer, push the container Grid down a bit (20px), and highlight the top part with a Rectangle.

Hope this is what you wanna achieve...

Comment: so what you wanna achieve? i thought you don't want that control to move right?

Comment: The ScrollBars should reach to top of window (they don't if I put the Canvas outside). And if I would lay Canvas over ScrollViewer I have to determine clipping of the content of ScrollViewer and size of LightBlue-Canvas. And I hope I can avoid this way, when I can stick the Row.

Comment: Example: WinWord. Show Rulers. The ruler are optical inside the ScrollViewer, but does not move.

Comment: but in word, the ruler is above the scrollviewer, which doesn't reach to the top of the window.

Comment: The word what I use, the vertical scrollbar looks like outside of horizontal Ruler. In my case it's just the other Orientation ;p

Comment: are you using wpf/silverlight/wp7?

Comment: alrite, please see my updated answer, basically you need a new style for your scrollviewer to have the scrollbar all the way to the top

Answer (score 0):

If the control is in `ScrollViewer`, it will scroll. If you don't want it to scroll, it shouldn't be in a ScrollViewer. Xin's suggestion of making the ScrollViewer behave like a "layer" or "overlay" on top or below the `Canvas` is about the only way to keep the Canvas in place and still let it expand to the whole window.

At least from your description, it sounds like you can't easily or practically do what you want to do.