# How do I access to a control element that is defined in a style

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I've a CustomControl which use a ScrollViewer. The following code is an example which shows my use case in an easy way:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:MyCustomControl">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:MyCustomControl">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Grid.Row="0"
                        Height="300" Width="400"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                        Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerStyle}">
            <Canvas x:Name="outer" Width="400" Height="400"
                    Background="Red" Margin="50">
              <Canvas x:Name="inner" Background="Green" 
                      Width="400" Height="400">
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                  <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}"
                                  ScaleY="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}"/>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
              </Canvas>
            </Canvas>
          </ScrollViewer>
        <Slider x:Name="slider" Minimum="0.1" Maximum ="10"
                Value="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I left out the nonrelevant CodeBehind belonging to Slider.ValueChanged.

In a further question I ask [How do I stick Controls inside of ScrollViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417844/how-do-i-stick-controls-inside-of-scrollviewer). In this answer I got the idea to template the ScrollViewer. I added some elements to the ScrollViewer as shown in the answer. For example I've a new Canvas inside of my ScrollViewer:

`<Canvas x:Name="canvas"/>`

I need access to this Canvas at runtime, so in WPF I created:

`public class MyScrollViewer : ScrollViewer`

I override `OnApplyTemplate` and get access to it via `GetTemplateChild`. So all done.

In SL this way is not possible since ScrollViewer is sealed.

Now I am looking for an other way to get access. I hoped VisualTreeHelper would help me, but I do not get the Canvas. Neither in CodeBehind of my custom control nor in the codebehind of my MainPage (where I use my control).

```
private void GetCanvas(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
  {
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject);
      Canvas canvas = child as Canvas;
      if (canvas == null)
      {
        GetCanvas(child);
      }
      else
      {
        // Code here if found
      }
    }
  }
```

Then a colleague remember me, that there exists the directive x:FieldModifier. I never used it before, just heard about it. I give it a try.

```
x:FieldModifier="public"
```

But no idea if it really give me the possibility to access from codebehind, even less how.

So, is there any way how I could access at my Canvas at runtime in Silverlight? Maybe there is maybe another solution in WPF itself, which also works on SL?

Comment: Doesn't `myCustomControl.Template.FindName("outer", myCustomControl)` work (where `myCustomControl` is the `x:Name` of `MyCustomControl` instance hosted in your XAML View)

Comment: @AngelWPF Oh, FindName is missing in Silverlight, isn't it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Silverlight, this is possible using the extension method GetVisualDescendants(DependencyObject) in the Silverlight toolkit. The following **should** work...

- Add a reference to System.Windows.Controls.Primitives
- Add using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives
- Call scrollViewer.GetVisualDescendants().OfType().FirstOrDefault(canvas => canvas.Name.Equals("yourCanvasName")

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure, If I understand it right, because I am not able to call GetVisualDescendants. Should this be inside the VisualTreeHelper-Method. If yes, I already do not get the ScrollViewer in there. And when I try it in OnApplyTemplate behind GetTemplateChild("scrollViewer") it also does not exists. Do I have to this in code behind of my custom control or is it (also) possible in MainPage?

Comment: Ok, I was missing include to System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit. Now I find GetVisualDescendants. I am going on...